# how can i add multiple images and preview them using react and express?

Tags: reactjs, express

im trying to add multiple images using react app and send them to backend code to store them in mongodb

here is the code for the backend : 
[link](https://github.com/decodejacques/upload-file-example/blob/master/backend/server.js)

and this is the frontend [link](https://github.com/decodejacques/upload-file-example/blob/master/frontend/src/App.js)

so this code works for just one image

i need to be able to add multiple images

Answer (score 0):

#### Server

Since you are using `multer`, change the [`upload.single()` function](https://github.com/decodejacques/upload-file-example/blob/826a64da354456d6262bac05ff9d601463e37827/backend/server.js#L27) to `upload.array()`.

For example:

```
app.post("/addItem", 
  upload.array('product-image', 4), // 'product-image' is field name and 4 is the max number of files allowed
  (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files);
    // ... rest of the logic
  }
)
```

Check out [docs for `upload.array()`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#arrayfieldname-maxcount)

#### Client

[Change current `<input>`](https://github.com/decodejacques/upload-file-example/blob/826a64da354456d6262bac05ff9d601463e37827/frontend/src/App.js#L63) to allow multiple files:

```
<input type="file" name="product-image" onChange={this.fileChangeHandler} multiple>
```

Now save all the images user picked [not only the `event.target.files[0]`](https://github.com/decodejacques/upload-file-example/blob/826a64da354456d6262bac05ff9d601463e37827/frontend/src/App.js#L18):

```
fileChangeHandler(event) {
    let files = event.target.files
    this.setState({ selectedFiles: files })
}
```

Now [add them in `FormData`](https://github.com/decodejacques/upload-file-example/blob/826a64da354456d6262bac05ff9d601463e37827/frontend/src/App.js#L30) and upload as usual:

```
let formData = new FormData()
formData.append("product-image", this.state.selectedFiles)
```

That's it! Hope it helps.

PS: I don't think files should be added to state. You can simply add them to a class variable. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54695033/4135289) I explained why and how to do that.

---

**Update:**

You need to loop over the files now. Your `/addItem` endpoint's code will look something like this:

```
app.post("/addItem", upload.array('product-image', 4), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.files);

  let paths = [];

  req.files.forEach(file => {
    console.log("new file location", file.path)

    let extension = file.originalname.split(".").pop()
    fs.rename(file.path, file.path + "." + extension, () => {})
    paths.push("/" + file.filename + "." + extension);
  });

  console.log("body", req.body)

  let itemToStore = {
    paths: paths,  // notice this `paths` now, it was `path`
    description: req.body.description
  }

  console.log("we are adding", itemToStore)
  itemData.push(itemToStore)
  console.log("updated itemData:", itemData)
  res.send(JSON.stringify(itemData))
})
```

I didn't modify your code, just added a loop. Your `'path' of undefined` error should go away.

Comment: i tried to do so but it doesn't work there is an error in server that the path is undefined. could you please try it and send me the result? when i upload files it shows me the number of files that i uploaded so the path is not defined. @mehamasum

Comment: Please share the full stack trace.

Comment: I think I guessed the error. You should loop over the files to save them now. Look at my updated answer.